# Android: Dx trouble writing output: already prepared

Tags: android, eclipse

When I am running an android app in eclipse ADT, "Dx trouble writing output: already prepared"
appears in the console, then the app runs as usual. What is the cause of this message and how can I fix this?

Comment: It's just an information. It tells you that you are already running the same version of your app on the same emulator.

Comment: No, it is not - an old version of the app gets deployed, changes are not seen on the device...

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem.

To fix this problem under eclipse menu select: **Project -> Clean ...** 
Select Your project and press **OK**.

**Restart Eclipse** (Optional)

Now just **Run** project.

Answer (score -3):

Try to do following steps
 1.restart the eclipse 
2.then uninstall app in ur device 
3.then re install it again.